# ErrorException (E_NOTICE) A non well formed numeric value encountered! Please i need an answer

Tags: laravel

Please my laravel project is showing `ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
A non well formed numeric value encountered` and i have tried all i could and still not working.

Here is my code

```
//if plan is starter
if ($plan_id == 1) {
    $newAmount = $Roi + $amount;
    if ($update_roi->addDays(1)->isPast() == true) {
        $new_roi = $newAmount * $starters / 100;

        $update = Investment::where('id', '=', $id)->update(['roi' => $new_roi, 'amount' => $newAmount, 'update_roi' => Carbon::now()]);
```

and i have tried all i could and it seems not to be working. I need a help please. The error is been generated from  on the picture.

[image: The error code]

Comment: What is the content of $Roi? (Also avoid to have $roi and $Roi variable, as it can cause confusion in your code)

Comment: Sorry for the late response! Thanks for your help